# The written link and condition is correct but the page does not move

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I want my login page to go to the contact confirmation page if I get number 200 from the server, but it does not work. Where is my mistake?

```
 const [form, setForm] = useState({});

 async function checkLogin() {
     try {
         const response = await axios({
             url: 'https://api.bms-go2tr.com/api/v1/check',
             method: 'POST',
             data: form
         });

         if (response.status == 200) {
             return <Link to="/Verification"/>
         }
     } catch (error) {
         if (error.status == 493) {
             return <Link to="/Verification" />
         } else {
             alert(error.response.data.message)
         }
     }
```

Comment: If you want to change page, you can use `useNavigate` hook for navigate programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant return JSX like this in a callback and expect it to be rendered into the DOM. In callback handlers like this you are wanting to issue an ***imperative*** navigation action (*i.e. using the `navigate` function*), versus a ***declarative*** action (*i.e. rendering a `Link` or `Navigate` component*).

Use the `useNavigate` hook to access the `navigate` function and replace the `Link` with a call to `navigate`.

Example:

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const navigate = useNavigate();
const [form, setForm] = useState({});

async function checkLogin() {
  try {
    const response = await axios({
      url: 'https://api.bms-go2tr.com/api/v1/check',
      method: 'POST',
      data: form
    });

    if (response.status == 200) {
      navigate("/Verification");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.status == 493) {
      navigate("/Verification");
    } else {
      alert(error.response.data.message);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`<Link>` Component is used to create link in your application but it don't navigate to that link. For Navigation you can use `useNavigate()` hook or `<Navigate>` Component(if you use react router v6).

**Solution:**
Instead of `<Link to="/Verification" />` use `<Navigate to="/Verification" />`.